# GNU GRUB - Is there any negative in using a grub text-only mode to boot into Ubuntu/Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, bios, text

Is "text" (`GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text`) an acceptable long-term grub setting? Can it be presumed that the "GUI" (Mint Cinnamon X server etc) will faithfully take over to normal function after "text" booting?

Detail:
New to GNU GRUB. Limited Linux and Unix experience. Seeking education on this to avoid any future problem. Perusing the manuals at gnu.org informed the workaround below.

Experienced "boot to black screen" type problems with installs in a certain legacy situation, nomodeset did not work, but rather adding `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text` to /etc/default/grub worked to boot as a "normal" quiet black screen which continues to open an apparently normally running Linux Mint 21.

(also noted that `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"` if paired with `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` worked similarly)

Final /etc/default/grub was

````
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text```
````

Answer (score 1):

#### No downside

At least none that I know of. There are some situations where the virtual terminal keeps the low resolution GRUB started with. However, this is irrelevant to you since you are using the graphical interface anyway.

Comment: Appreciate the info.